# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation - An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. DbGeography

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, invocationtargetexception

Before I say anything - yes, I've read everything on this question so far, about building in X86/X64 modes and so on. I recently changed PC and have set up my environment again. The code is from a reporting service within a silverlight application. The silverlight application all builds fine and it has been publish ok as well. It just seems there are a few small errors somewhere within the reporting section that don't seem to want to play nice.

```
double Latitude = (double) parameters["GeofenceLatitude"];
double Longitude = (double) parameters["GeofenceLongitude"];
double Radius = (double) parameters["GeofenceRadius"];
DbGeography Geofence = GetPointFromLatLong(Latitude, Longitude);

Geofence = Geofence.Buffer(Radius);
```

So everything works fine, the `GetPointFromLatLong` method (a custom one) returns a correct `DbGeography` object, however the `.Buffer(Radius)` causes an exception detailed below.

> InnerException = {"An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"}
>
> Message = "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."
>
> Source = "mscorlib"
>
> StackTrace = "at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlSpatialServices.Buffer(DbGeography geographyValue, Double distance) at System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography.Buffer(Nullable distance) at GpsSilverlight.Web.Reports.ReportService.OnLoadData(IDictionary`2 parameters, String reportName, ReportSlot reportSlot) in PROJECT:line 1514"

I cannot figure out what's going on here. Does anyone have any experience with this?

```
static DbGeography GetPointFromLatLong(double Latitude, double Longitude)
    {
        DbGeography geogTest;
        geogTest = DbGeography.PointFromText(string.Format("POINT({1} {0})", Latitude.ToString(), Longitude.ToString()), 4326);

        return geogTest;
    }
```

Comment: You stated you read it all.... but anyway have you checked the Configuration Manager? Sometimes the solution configuration is messed up, especially when you change the PC/recreate the repository...

Comment: Yep, Identical! http://i.imgur.com/2rIUjqG.png

Comment: When debugging, is there an inner exception with any more details of the error? Show the `GetPointFromLatLong` method

Comment: I've edited in the GetPointFromLatLong, which returns correctly.

Comment: The Inner Exception is:
InnerException = {"An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"}
StackTrace = "   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GLNativeMethods.GeodeticAngleExtent(GeoMarshalData g, Double eccentricity, Double& result)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GLNativeMethods.GeodeticAngleExtent(GeoData g, Double eccentricity)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.T...

Comment: Just google "dbgeography 64-bit", lots of hits.

Answer (score 0):

The most common problem when this exception is thrown is that the CLR is running in 32/64 bit mode and is attempting to load an assembly compiled for 64/32 bit mode.

Sometimes solution, project and configuration settings can be a bit confusing and not always producing binaries the way you think.

The best way to verify what the compiler REALLY has done to build your assemblies (or ones you rely on) is to disassemble them and look at the assembly manifest information of all your binaries. Often one assembly is not built in the configuration you think it should.

This type of problem still bugs me sometimes and disassembling usually helps.